# SQL: Reordering List Order

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to loop through a table row.. reorder my "Form Options" by setting the OrderID to @NUMCOUNT...

I want to be able to rearrange the order of my List. The reason I need to do this is because if I delete a Form Option then it will be out of order.. i.e (1, 2, 3, 5).. I will want (1, 2, 3, 4).. etc..

Example table:

ID OrderID FormOption

1   1      Name

2   3      Address 2

3   2      Address 1

```
DECLARE @NUMCOUNT int
SET @NUMCOUNT = 0
WHILE (SELECT Count(OrderID) FROM FormOptions WHERE ProductID=1) > @NUMCOUNT
BEGIN
   SET @NUMCOUNT = @NUMCOUNT + 1
   PRINT 'The count is ' + CAST(@NUMCOUNT as char)
   UPDATE FormOptions SET OrderID = @NUMCOUNT WHERE ID=????
END
```

Comment: Don't understand  1,2,3,5 is still ordered.  you want to re-assign all your orderID values to be contiguous?

Comment: By "SQL" do you mean "Transact-SQL"?

Comment: Yes! T-SQL... the thing is.. when I add an item.. it counts... so I have 4.. then it adds to this list and there are 2 5's.. so I would want to reorder the list.

Comment: TSQL means either Sybase or SQL Server - which are you using, and what version specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by "it counts"?  It will only have two 5's if you inserted two fives.  Need table definition, insert statement, and delete statement.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you are working on something that needs to allow deleting from an ordered list and inserting into an ordered list at a specific position.  Deleting doesn't require making the order dense, but it can be done:

```
delete from FormOptions
  where OrderId = @SelectedFormOption
update FormOptions
  set OrderId = OrderId - 1
  where OrderId > @SelectedFormOption
```

You may want to wrap that in a transaction.  *(Make sure that you understand transactions as this is rather important.)*

Inserting is similar:

```
update FormOptions
  set OrderId = OrderId + 1
  where OrderId >= @TargetOrderId
insert into FormOptions
  ( OrderId, ... ) values ( @TargetOrderId, ... )
```

Swapping order positions may be done atomically in a single update:

```
 update FormOptions
   set OrderId = case when OrderId = @TargetA then @TargetB else @TargetB end
   where OrderId in ( @TargetA, @TargetB )
```

A similar `update` can be written to move a single form option up or down one position in the order.

Comment: Not sure why this isnt accepted answer, as it not only provides the answer but also provides solution for position swaping which most would probably do with few updates instead of a single one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest leaving OrderId alone as @OldProgrammer has said they will still be in order, plus (unless i'm missing something) it would seem to add unnecessary overhead.

If you really want to have continuous numbers, presumably for presentation purposes, then either push that to the presentation tier, or create a view which would do something like

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() AS OrderNumber
    , OtherColumn
FROM FormOptions 
ORDER BY OrderID
```

Comment: ID OrderID FormOption
1   1      Name
2   3      Address 2
3   2      Address 1

Comment: Rearange the list from where, when and how. For example if I set the item at 8 to be at 4 do they switch place or all 'move down' one? Is only one item moved at once? When you add an item rather then use a `COUNT+1` why not use `MAX+1`?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against not using counting for ordering.  In the past I've had multiple columns for ordering based on whatever the user decided.

One option to quickly fix the issue is to give an orderID > Max(orderID)  That way you ensure each new item gets an orderID > than the highest value, regardless of number of items in the list.

You can then have a column just for sorting purposes and allow users to set the order of things.

Sometimes it's easier (and better) to think of how you can change what you're doing, rather than code to do what your thinking :)