# Handling custom defined sequence number through out the database table row data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a table with an `int` `[sequence]` number column that indicates the display order of the data in the table. Users can update this order by editing the sequence number from the front end. I am using SQL Server database

There are a few ways to change sequence number order and can update sequence number positions.

1). When a row is added, it should add the following sequence number

2). When a row is deleted, it should rearrange sequence numbers (Note: Delete is soft delete using the `[IsDelete]` boolean column. At that time sequence should be 0)

3). When a user changes one sequence to another, other sequences should automatically be updated.

For example: if one sequence was moved to 2nd from 4th and this sequence was moved from 3rd to 6th then every other column should automatically move up/down accordingly, and their sequences should get updated.

Here is the data table design
[image]

Also here are the DDL and DML of the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NULL,
    [IsStandard] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DeletedBy] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RegisterConfiguration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RISK_RegisterConfiguration_IsStandard]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsStandard]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RISK_RegisterConfiguration_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RISK_RegisterConfiguration_CreatedBy]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CreatedBy]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_RISK_RegisterConfiguration_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 1', 'Test 1', 1, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 2', 'Test 2', 2, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 3', 'Test 3', 3, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 4', 'Test 4', 4, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 5', 'Test 5', 0, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 1, '2022-7-19', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 6', 'Test 6', 0, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 1, '2022-7-19', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 7', 'Test 7', 0, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 1, '2022-7-19', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 8', 'Test 8', 5, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 9', 'Test 9', 6, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 10', 'Test 10', 7, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 11', 'Test 11', 8, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 12', 'Test 12', 0, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 1, '2022-7-19', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 13', 'Test 13', 0, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 1, '2022-7-19', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 15', 'Test 14', 9, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RegisterConfiguration] ([Name],[Description],[Sequence],[IsStandard],[CreatedDate],[CreatedBy],[ModifiedDate],[ModifiedBy],[IsDeleted],[DeletedDate],[DeletedBy]) VALUES ('Test 16', 'Test 15', 10, 1, '2022-7-19', 1, null,null, 0, null, null)
```

I am thinking about a **trigger** or a **stored procedure** to fulfill this requirement.

Can you give me some guidance about this requirement?

****Update****_
Here is the view of the frontend table
[image]

Comment: Otherwise seems fairly straight forward, a default for new records, and a SP for when a user reorders. What options have you considered? What are you unsure about?

Comment: @DaleK ```[Sequence]``` also displayed in the front end table as below.

Comment: @DaleK updated question expected view

Comment: You might get some insights from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858191/92546) answer.